# Opening csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv

I have a .csv file having multiple rows and columns:

```
chain   Resid   Res K   B   C   Tr  Kw  Bw  Cw  Tw

A   1   ASP 1   0   0.000104504 NA  0   0   0.100087974 0.573972285
A   2   GLU 2   627 0.000111832 0   0.033974309 0.004533331 0.107822844 0.441666022
```

Whenever I open the file using pandas or using with open, it shows that there are only column and multiple rows:

```
629 rows x 1 columns
```

Here is the code im using:

```
data= pd.read_csv("F:/file.csv", sep='\t')
print(data)
```

and the result I'm getting is this"

```
A,1,ASP,1,0,0.0001045041279130...
```

I want the output to be in a dataframe form so that I can carry out future calculations. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: there is separator `,`, so need `data= pd.read_csv("F:/file.csv")`, because `sep=','` is default sep

Comment: Thanks for the help, it did work for me. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is separator `,`, so is psosible omit parameter `sep`, because `sep=','` is deafault separator in `read_csv`:

```
data= pd.read_csv("F:/file.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can read the csv using the following code snippet

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv('F:/file.csv', sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `'\t'`, because you don't have four consecutive spaces together (a tab between), so use the below:

```
data = pd.read_csv("F:/file.csv")
```

Or if really needed, use:

```
data = pd.read_csv("F:/file.csv", sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
```

If your data values have spaces.